# ESG Style Analysis

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, sharpe-ratio, portfolio-theory

Hi all and thank you in advance.

Do you think that implementing a style analysis on ESG equity portfolios is feasible?

When I mean style analysis I refer to the seminal paper of Sharpe (1992) but I this case explain the performance of funds through indices that relate to high/medium/low ESG.

Does anyone know if such indicators exist and if not has anyone been through the quantification of ESG factors?

Thank you.

Comment: An interesting article came out in Risk Magazine: Fuzzy data stalls ESG alpha hunt. "Quants searching for ESG signals have reached very different conclusions. Mostly they blame the data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is feasible. You can check out this paper:  [A Blueprint for Integrating ESG into Equity Portfolios](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3080381)

One of the main challenges is finding the appropriate data to perform your analysis.

If you have access to a Bloomberg terminal, you can look at some of the recent webinar material (Seeing Green Spotlight Webinar) on ESG analysis that Bloomberg is using to promote it's `BQNT` (Jupyter environment inside the Bloomberg terminal) and `BQL` (new query language to extract Bloomberg information) tools.

**Part 1 - ESG Scoring App Workflows**

- Access the new ESG data available in BQL for your target universe
- Use the BQuant app template to quickly build your own ESG scoring app

**Part 2 - Integrating Your Research into ESG Scoring Models**

- Use Bloomberg's custom data editor (CDE) to upload your research
- Combine your research and BQuant's ESG score in a single scoring app

**Part 3 - Finding ESG Bonds**

- Create an interactive app with ESG scores for a bond universe
- Identify companies that have issued green bonds

**Part 4 - Improving Your Portfolio's ESG Score**

- Visualize the largest detractors to your portfolio's ESG score
- Construct scenarios to determine the ESG impact of specific companies

Comment: Thank you David! Your answer was indeed enlightening.